# TextTrimming property does not work for a custom TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I've created a "bindable" `TextBlock`, that is, a textblock which is bound to items, and those items have properties that define how the text should be rendered (color, for example).

However, the ´TextTrimming` property does not work for my custom textblock, here's the code:

```
class BindableTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public BindableTextBlock()
    {

    }

    public bool HideWhenEmpty
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(HideWhenEmptyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HideWhenEmptyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HideWhenEmptyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HideWhenEmpty", typeof(bool), typeof(BindableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

    public ObservableCollection<DescriptionToken> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<DescriptionToken>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<DescriptionToken>), typeof(BindableTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnItemsPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((BindableTextBlock)d).OnItemsChanged();
    }

    private void OnItemsChanged()
    {
        if (Items == null)
            return;
        Items.CollectionChanged -= ItemsCollectionChanged;
        Items.CollectionChanged += ItemsCollectionChanged;

        BuildText();
    }

    private void BuildText()
    {
        Inlines.Clear();
        if (Items == null || !Items.Any())
        {
            if (HideWhenEmpty)
                Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            return;
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var item = Items[i];
            var run = new Run(TruncateText(item.Text));
            if (item.IsVariable)
            {
                run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(item.IsError ? Colors.Red : Colors.Blue);
                run.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
            }
            Inlines.Add(run);
        }

        Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private string TruncateText(string text)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            return text;

        if (text.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
            return TruncateText(text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine)) + "...");

        if (text.Length > 120)
        {
            var result = text.Substring(0, 120).TrimEnd('.');
            return result + "...";
        }

        return text;
    }

    private void ItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BuildText();
    }
```

Whenever `Items` changed, it manipulates `TextBlock.Inlines` in order to set text color.

**XAML**

```
<DataTemplate>
 <Border Padding="3">
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">

                <TextBlock Text="aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbb cccccccccc ddddddddddd eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee ffffffffffffffffff ggggggggggg" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="10" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
                <controls:BindableTextBlock Items="{Binding Description}" FontSize="10"
                                            FontStyle="Italic" HideWhenEmpty="True"
                                            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
       </DataTemplate>
```

The following image shows that the 1st `TextBlock` is trimmed, but the 2nd (mine) is not:
[image]

How to make my custom `TextBlock` work just like the regular `TextBlock` does regarding `TextTrimming` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your control wraps, it cannot trim.
So remove this code:

```
TextWrapping = System.Windows.TextWrapping.Wrap;
```

from your control's constructor.